# WCF Contract Generation

Tags: wcf

Is there way to change the wcf contract from.

This

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  **<AddCustomer>**
     <!--Optional:-->
     <Data>
        <ns:AddressLine1>?</ns:AddressLine1>
        <ns:AddressLine2>?</ns:AddressLine2>
        <ns:City>?</ns:City>
        <ns:Country>?</ns:Country>
        <ns:Email>?</ns:Email>
        <ns:FirstName>?</ns:FirstName>
        <ns:HomePhone>?</ns:HomePhone>
        <ns:ID>?</ns:ID>
        <ns:LastName>?</ns:LastName>
        <ns:MobilePhone>?</ns:MobilePhone>
        <ns:State>?</ns:State>
        <ns:Suburb>?</ns:Suburb>
     </Data>
  **</AddCustomer>**
```

To

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:biz="http://BizTalk.Test001.Customer">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <biz:Data>
     <ID>?</ID>
     <FirstName>?</FirstName>
     <LastName>?</LastName>
     <MobilePhone>?</MobilePhone>
     <HomePhone>?</HomePhone>
     <Email>?</Email>
     <AddressLine1>?</AddressLine1>
     <AddressLine2>?</AddressLine2>
     <Suburb>?</Suburb>
     <City>?</City>
     <State>?</State>
     <Country>?</Country>
  </biz:Data>
```

Basically i want to get rid of  "AddCustomer" from the request. Can we do something using ServiceContract or OperationContract.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement IClientMessageInspector interface.So before sending a request or after receving the response you need to implement your own C# methods to override your request /response SOAP messages like,

```
 public class ClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public string LastRequestXml { get; private set; }
        public string LastResponseXml { get; private set; }
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            LastResponseXml = reply.ToString();
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
        {
            LastRequestXml = request.ToString();
            var xmlPayload = ChangeMessage();
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
            writer.Write(xmlPayload);
            writer.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;

            var reader = XmlReader.Create(ms);
            request = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
            var payload = request.ToString();
            return request;
        }

        /// Manipulate the SOAP message
        private string ChangeMessage()
     {
               //manipulation code here to remove AddCustomer.
     }
}
```

For detail implementation check out this blog.
https://cmatskas.com/changing-soap-message-data-and-namespaces-with-c/